# Segmentation fault due to memory alignment in SSE

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I am working on face detection, in which I am taking input as a .bmp file and detecting the face and drawing a rectangle on the face.

But when I am adding a function called "cvDetect" to detect the face i am getting some segmentation fault, in the following line of code-

```
_mm_store_ps(&c(y, 4.0*x), _mm_sub_ps(_mm_load_ps(a.data(y, 4.0*x)), _mm_load_ps(b.data(y, 4.0*x))));
```

While debugging I found that there is some memory alignment problem due to these functions. Can anyone help in solving this problem, the code is in C++ and I am using Linux.

Comment: Took me a bit of staring at Google results to realize you were talking about language extensions for SSE...

Comment: yes i am talking about SSE only.. but dnt knw how to resolve it.. I am new to coding and dnt knw much abt it,,

Comment: NO I AM NOT USING OPENCV

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know anything about these SSE extensions, but it sounds like you are having trouble aligning your variables.  To declare a particular alignment with a variable declaration requires non-portable extensions, varying by your compiler.

For GCC you'd declare your variable something like this:

```
// Declare a variable called 'a' of type __m128, aligned at 16 bytes.
__m128 a __attribute__((aligned (16)));
```

For Microsoft Visual C++ you'd do something like this:

```
__declspec(align(16)) __m128 a;
```

Comment: yah i did like this - typedef float __m128 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__)); and i m using gcc..

Comment: I think `float` will be way too small for this.  What happens when you do `typedef char m128[16] __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));` ?

Comment: @kamakshi: If alignment is the issue, then this is the answer. Now, I agree with @asveikau that the issue might be the size of the variable, in which case this is a great example of how asking the wrong question will mislead people into wrong answers --the question is quite clear in that you *know* that the issue is alignment.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for now would be to use unaligned loads and stores, i.e.

```
_mm_storeu_ps(&c(y, 4.0*x), _mm_sub_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(a.data(y, 4.0*x)), _mm_loadu_ps(b.data(y, 4.0*x))));
```

There will be a performance hit, unless you are using Core i5/i7, but at least it will work correctly.

Ultimately though you need to look at ensuring that your data is always 16 byte aligned.

Comment: how will i know that the data is 16 byte alligned?

Comment: You either need to allocate it dynamically with a library call that can guarantee alignment, e.g. `memalign` or `_mm_malloc`, or use static allocation with either a suitable underlying vector type, e.g. `__m128i`, or with a compiler-specific alignment qualifier, e.g. `__attribute__ ((aligned(16)))`.

Answer (score 0):

`_ps` functions require 16-byte aligned memory operands

Comment: yah that i knw,, but wat shud i change  to remove this segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a.data(r, c) is a call for an operator() on an object called a, which returns a reference to some memory.

This memory should have been either allocated using **_mm_malloc** or **[_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28VS.80%29.aspx)** if you're using Visual Studio (and not **new** or **malloc**).

If the memory is not dynamically allocated, but is a field in some object, the field should be declared with an alignment attribute like the one specified in asveikau's reply.

Comment: If _mm_malloc or _aligned_malloc is not available we could do following: char* Ptr = new char[Count + 16]; char* Ptr2 = (char*) (((intptr_t) Ptr + 15) & ~15); In this case, Ptr2 is always 16 byte aligned.